# Extracting specific values from a multi-dimensional list

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

### Hi all,

I'm fairly new to python and can't find a solution to a problem- and was wondering if anybody could point me towards a function or solution which would help.
I have coded a 7x6 grid in turtle graphics which places four individual tokens into columns based on randomly generated 'moves' -similar to the game connect four. At the end of this I have made a multi-dimensional list recording each 'move', including the column, row and which token, which looks similar to this:

```
[column, row, player] --for context
[['g', 0, 'token1'], ['f', 0, 'token3'], ['e', 0, 'token2'], ['d', 0, 'token4'], ['a', 0, 'token1']]
```

Based on this data I'd like to find out who has the top token of each column at the end of the game. I'm trying to do this by extracting all elements or 'turns' from the larger list that includes column 'a' for example, and putting them into their own list. From there I'd try to find which has the max row value, leaving me with one turn that would be the highest token in the column
Only problem is I don't know where to begin with coding- I know python has a list() function however I don't know how to place in a "where column == 'a'" parameter into it. I also know of a max() function that could help find the maximum row value, however I don't know how to find a single maximum value in a list as it will just return the element with the most characters- if I were to turn the smaller lists into dictionaries would that help with the max() function? 
I understand that most questions on here have some base code which is helpfully edited to find a solution- and as my question doesn't contain any code I'd like to make it clear that **I am not asking anybody to code this for me**- I'm just looking for advice on functions or methods to solve this issue as the internet hasn't been very helpful.
Much thanks :)

Comment: Show us your code for your grid so we know what we are working with

Comment: @GrandPhuba Sorry I forgot to mention- the grid is coded with turtle graphics and each square has an associated x and y co-ordinate, so based on the randomly generated move the turtle moves to the square and draws a token